# Prove sum of distance from triangle vertices to a point inside triangle is more than semiperimeter and less than perimeter

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> If $O$ is a point inside $\triangle ABC$,Prove: $$\frac{\overline{AB}+\overline{BC}+\overline{CA}}{2}<\overline{AO}+\overline{BO}+\overline{CO}<\overline{AB}+\overline{BC}+\overline{CA}$$

**Figure**
[image]

*Things I have done:* I was able to proof second part 
$$Proof \space of \space second \space part\\\\
\begin{array}{ l| l }
\hline
Statement & Reasoning \\
\hline
\overline{AB}+\overline{AE} > \overline{BE} & Triangle\space inequality \\
\overline{OE}+\overline{CE} > \overline{OC} & Triangle\space inequality \\
\overline{AB}+\overline{AC} > \overline{OC} + \overline{OB} & By \space statement\space 1 \space and \space 2 \\
\overline{AC}+\overline{BC} > \overline{OA} + \overline{OB} & Similar \space to \space statement\space 1 \space and \space 2 \space and \space 3 \\
\overline{AB}+\overline{BC} > \overline{OA} + \overline{OB} & Similar \space to \space statement\space 1 \space and \space 2 \space and \space 3 \\
\overline{AO}+\overline{BO}+\overline{CO}<\overline{AB}+\overline{BC}+\overline{CA}  & By \space statement\space 3 \space and \space 4 \space and \space 5\\
\end{array}$$

For the first inequality which is between semiperimeter and sum of distances from vertices, I don't know what to do. I think my approach for the second inequality can't be applied to proving this one.

Comment: AO+BO>AB, BO+CO>BC, CO+AO>AC, add it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality,
$$
OA+OB>AB;\\
OA+OC>AC;\\
OB+OC>BC.
$$
Summing these and dividing by 2 give you the first inequality.